# Why am I recieving an garbage value

Tags: anchor, solana-program, web3.js, rust, anchor-client

````
// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("CEUKfCKpDNgk6sqNwnQWZ1Xdjb6ujYyrJkrh3HpNn489");

#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, name: u64,value:u64) -> Result<()> {
        let new_account =&mut ctx.accounts.new_account;
        new_account.data  = name + value;
        new_account.data1 = name - value;
        new_account.data2 = name * value;
        new_account.data3 = name / value;
        // Message will show up in the tx logs
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    // We must specify the space in order to initialize an account.
    // First 8 bytes are default account discriminator,
    // next 8 bytes come from NewAccount.data being type u64.
    // (u64 = 64 bits unsigned integer = 8 bytes)
    #[account(init, payer = signer, space = 8 + 32)]
    pub new_account: Account<'info, NewAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct NewAccount {
    data: u64,
    data1:u64,
    data2:u64,
    data3:u64
}```
This is the code, which takes in 2 values and Performs Simple arithmetic calculations. 
As you can see by the image, the value returned by data1 is a huge garbage value. I am trying to understand how did it even appear, and how is it possible to store such a huge value in u64.
[![enter image description here][1]][1] 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fS5Z.png
````

Answer (score 1):

It's not advisable to use plain `+, -, *, and /` for operations in a Solana program and the use of those operators constitute a security risk(due to overflow/underflow). Use `checked_add(), checked_sub(), checked_mul(), and checked_div()` instead.

For example:

```
new_account.data = name.checked_add(value);
```